# php race condition database with row entries

Tags: php, mysql, race-condition

So im trying to figure out how to avoid a race condition.
I have a product where you can make bookings on resources that are limited.

Each resource has a number of capacity. A capacity is calculated with number of rows in a database table called booking_resources where each resource booked has a row.

During code execution i do a multiple of checks for example:

- Does this person have access
- Is the resource available in the given timeframe
- Does booking options validate
- make the booking

When "making the booking" the resources needed for the booking are inserted into the booking_resources table. This makes the number of rows that has resource_id grow which in turn will make the next check on is resource available in a giving timeframe.
My problem is i cannot find any documentation on what to do in this case.
Should i add an extra column in my resource table and in this way lock the row? (i use **innodb**)

I've read something about using select ... for update.. but this doesnt make sense in my case, because i dont "cache" the number of bookings in the row.
The whole idea is that i have a resource that is available 24/7, and each booking takes some of its capacity. It might have a capacity of 10 (which means that i can have 10 people using the resource at the same time). This also means that (theoretically) peoples bookings of resources can overlap as long as no more than 10 people are using it at the same time.

Hope my question gives an idea of the problem im facing and hope you guys have an elegant solution that will prevent overbooking in my application.

data structure:

bookings:

> id | company_id | points | from | to | price | booking_data | booker_choises | due_order_id_datetime (when booking is deleted if not part of order) | created | updated | deleted

booking_resources:

> id | booking_id | resource_id | from | to | points | created | updated | deleted

resources:

> id | company_id | name | min_booking | max_bookings | min_points | max_points | created | updated | deleted

To be able to reproduce the issue i have made a javascript that clicks on the same button on the same time in two different windows. This is done by using a settimeout timer and click event (using jquery).

```
<script>
function syncClick(selector,time_to_activate){
    date = new Date();
    if(date.getTime() >= time_to_activate){
        console.log('clicked');
        jQuery(selector).click();
    } else {
        setTimeout(function(){
            console.log("diff:"+(date.getTime() - time_to_activate));
            syncClick(selector,time_to_activate);
        },1);
    }
}
</script>
```

Thanks.
/W

Comment: are you using transactions?

Comment: well...no.. but this is only because i cannot see how the transaction would help here. do they actually lock the table itself? so only 1 thing can be inserted at a time? 
do i have to do an insert and afterwards "check" that it still holds and if not then make one of the transactions "rollback"?

Comment: Well if you're doing multiple database add/update/delete operations as part of one sequence, then it would be advisable in order to prevent inconsistent data if a statement fails or cannot be executed (e.g. because it fails a test such as something being available). It's not clear if that's part of your scenario but sounds like it might be. It may not be the solution to your issue but it should help in other ways.

Comment: Anyway you haven't really given us a truly clear picture of the situation. We can't see your actual data structure or how you calculate the capacity. But ideally if someone is enquiring about a particular period of time, you should perhaps lock that to them temporarily until they confirm. And give them a time limit until their exclusive access ends. A lot of ticket websites do this for popular events - you select a number of tickets, and then you have a few minutes to confirm the booking and make payment, before they are released back to the public again and you might lose it.

Comment: i'll comment on all of the things you write in a sec. Just to give a clear picture. "this" is the actually locking of the timeframe. When a booking is created you have X minutes to confirm (create the order - and make the payment)..

Comment: Ok then if you already have that, what's the issue? Doesn't that stop people from taking the resource over its capacity?

Comment: No, since if two people click on book at the same time (and we then start the checking and insert into db) they are both inserted.
But are you telling me that if use transactions on this kind no new inserts in the table will be made until other inserts have finished? i just dont want to end up in a deadlock situation

Comment: Depends on the lock level you employ, so potentially you could do that. But...you said " if two people click on book at the same time"...so the database will still process the queries sequentially. At what moment do you check the capacity of the room? You should do it again at the very last moment before you add the booking record. Then if it's already reserved or confirmed by someone else it can still reject it.

Comment: Also I don't see where in your data structure you are storing the fact that someone has reserved a slot, but not confirmed it? Really you want to prevent two people from _reserving_ a slot. Then it will never be possible for multiple _confirmations_ to occur.

Comment: To prevent a "race condition" (duplicate data in your case), you use `unique` constraint. Period. Nothing else exists in this universe that will do the job, `unique` constraint was MADE for that purpose. If your schema doesn't have any condition for uniqueness, your schema is bad and should be improved. No transaction, no check, no language, no isolation level exists, nothing. You *have* to add uniqueness condition. Only that way can you prevent multiple records getting in when they shouldn't. Or, you can completely disregard what I wrote and continue your way.

Comment: @N.B. Thanks for your input. The problem at hand is that we have a resource that can be booked by multiple people. This means that a single resource is available at all times but only for 10 people at any time.
Making anything unique in this case is not possible, Not even a unique set. But thanks anyway

Comment: That's not correct, you do have uniqueness available. You are implementing it but not on db level. Yes, it requires slight alteration of your schema, but if you can implement fake uniqueness, you can implement real one.

Comment: @N.B. I don't think uniqueness of anything is the issue here. OP is not trying to prevent duplicate records from being inserted, but rather to prevent _too many_ records from being inserted which would cause a particular resource, at a particular point in time, to be filled beyond its defined capacity.

Comment: @ADyson exactly, and that IS uniqueness, no matter what you might think of it. Capacity + filled capacity = unique. If filled > available, error. Easily sorted with constraints. I'll post once I catch 20 minutes of free time.

Comment: @N.B. perhaps I don't know enough about constraints but how could you set a `unique` constraints across multiple tables? The capacity is defined on the resource. The amount of capacity used is essentially the number of rows in the bookings table pertaining to the specific resource and time period. It's also not clear from the data whether there are fixed timeslots to check against, or whether any period of time can be defined, and we have to check for abitrary overlaps.

Comment: @ADyson Thanks for your feedback. Please make an answer so i can accept it.
The solution i've made is by introducing transactions and after i've done the inserts i try to recalculate capacity. This way i am able to prevent too many inserts.

Comment: @ADyson Using the above javascript i was both able to reproduce the too-many inserts and after introducing the transaction+check i was able to prevent one of them to go through..

Answer (score -2):

So for following case:

UserA and UserB check BookA for availability on monday. So it will show "Available" after they both check. Use a stored procedure "sp_CheckAvail" that checks availability. It should return true in both cases.

Now UserA requests to book it for monday so clicks "book". The Book will get reserved for monday.

The request should look like this:

```
call sp_CheckAvail(bookid, $date, available); //This function will check 
                                              //wheter the book is available at the moment
                                              of the request

if available
    BEGIN
      insert into reservations(bookid, date)
      values($book, $date);  //This will write the reservation only if the book is available
    END

select available as result;
```

Of cource this must all run within a transaction, so even if the click on the link at the very same moment, only one client will get the reservation.

Please understand I can't write a complete query for you. But this way it will work.

Comment: I don't understand the downvoting. If there was a way to make a database constraint about the date range, I would prefer and recommend to do this. But as he needs to check that range, it's better this way. For distributed application it's important, to check in a transaction again before doing something.